# Get first or second values from a comma separated value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that stores data like `(42,12)`. Now I want to fetch 42 or 12 (two different select queries). I have searched and found some similar but much more complex scenarios. Is there any easy way of doing it? I am using MSSQL Server 2005.

Given there will always be only two values and they will be integer

Comment: Keep in mind that per-row functions do not scale well. The *right* way to handle this is to separate the column into two separate columns (or, if you can't change the incoming data, use an insert/update trigger to copy the parts into two other columns - at least that way you amortize the cost of the split across all selects (database tables are almost always read far more than written)). But, being pragmatic, I know this is sometimes not possible, which is why this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT '42,12'

SELECT  *,
        CAST(LEFT(Val,CHARINDEX(',',Val)-1) AS INT) FirstValue,
        CAST(RIGHT(Val,LEN(Val) - CHARINDEX(',',Val)) AS INT) SecondValue
FROM    @Table
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason you have this problem is because the database (which you may not have any control over), violates first normal form. Among other things, first normal form says that each column should hold a single value, not multiple values. This is bad design.

Now, having said this, the first solution that pops into my head is to write a UDF that parses the value in this column, based on the delimiter and returns either the first or second value.

Comment: Agree with UDF's, and the comment about bad design... Since you state there will only ever be two values, then use two dbFields.

Comment: The schema is defined long time ago and at that time the requirements was not there. Also I can not change the schema now as it will break everything. Also the table is used as all purpose. ( There might be other values in that column for other type of information for other types that I don't care.

Comment: Actually I am getting a comma separated list of values as a parameter from my application, so in my case this has nothing to do with bad design, or am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ',', 1)
```

Note: Its not the efficient way of doing things in rdbms. Consider normalizing your Database.